# i want to invite friends by posting on there wall with facebook sdk

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

My app is not a game and i want to invite friends by posting on there wall..
I tried this with

```js
function newInvite(){
        var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({
                method : 'apprequests',
                message: 'Come on man checkout my applications. visit http://ithinkdiff.net'
            }
        );
        //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
    }
```

but this does not work as it gives notification bt does not  post on my friends wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting on the wall of a friend (who does not even use your App) is not possible, Facebook removed that possibility a long time ago because it would always be spam.

The appropriate way to invite friends to your app is by using App Requests (only if it´s a game) or the send dialog.